# Как правильно склоняется аббревиатура: «ЗАГС» или «ЗАГСа»?

Tags: орфография, склонение, аббревиатуры

*Работник ЗАГСа вводит информацию о прописке ребенка.*

Answer (score 1):

Всю жизнь "ЗАГС" склонялся.

Answer (score 1):

Вот что имеется в ПАС под редакцией Лопатина:

> [**§ 205**](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=94#pp94). Звуковые инициальные аббревиатуры пишутся прописными буквами, напр.: *ООН, МИД, НОТ, ОМОН, ГАИ, СПИД, ГЭС, ГРЭС*. По традиции пишутся строчными буквами некоторые (немногие) звуковые аббревиатуры: *вуз, втуз, дот, дзот.* Отдельные звуковые аббревиатуры могут писаться и прописными, и строчными буквами, напр.: *НЭП* и *нэп, **ЗАГС*** и ***загс**.*
> При склонении звуковых аббревиатур окончания пишутся только строчными буквами (без отделения окончания от аббревиатуры дефисом или апострофом), напр.: *рабочие ЗИЛа, работать в МИДе, пьеса поставлена МХАТом.*

Склоняются обе аббревиатуры. Но если имеется родовое (поясняющее) слово, то аббревиатура, оформленная прописными буквами, не склоняется.
В орфографическом словаре:
[**загс**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%81), -а и **ЗАГС**, -а и *неизм.* (отдел ЗАГС) (*сокр.*: запись актов гражданского состояния).

- *Работник **ЗАГСа** вводит информацию о прописке ребенка.*

***В ЗАГСе** молодожены стояли на большом цветастом ковре* (Алла Сурикова).
*И справлять свадьбы тоже не было принято, расписались **в загсе*** (Анатолий Рыбаков).

- *Работник **отдела ЗАГС** вводит информацию о прописке ребенка.*

*В честь этого события торжественные мероприятия прошли в 22 **отделах ЗАГС** Новгородской области* ( «Новгородские ведомости», 2013).
*В моей шкатулке хранится свидетельство о рождении Александра, выданное **бюро ЗАГС** Смольнинского района Ленинграда* (Дмитрий Каралис).

Вывод: *загс* склоняется всегда, а *ЗАГС* — нет.